# Multiple Imporranges without empty cells

Tags: google-sheets

So I'm trying to import data from two different google sheets into the same column. Since new data will be put into each column I have to import the whole thing. My problem is that I can just use two import ranges with a lot of empty cells between the relevant date, but no one wants that. After trying a lot and googling like made I came up with this:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RwSw-JvLO3yqJxwQ9FBdfTcUjtSKlMMF3GF0Al-mGu8/edit#gid=286899333", "Sheet1!A1:A");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RwSw-JvLO3yqJxwQ9FBdfTcUjtSKlMMF3GF0Al-mGu8/edit#gid=286899333", "Sheet1!B1:B");},
"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 != ''")
```

But that also does not work. I set up an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yr5f4eMsnbUuhzdCNQk2RkKmXoyU3WHhn1PBcWqZvgU/edit#gid=286899333

I hope someone here understands my problem and is able to help me.

Comment: I realized I should have formatted the code better:

`=QUERY
({IMPORTRANGE("data","Sheet1!A1:A");
IMPORTRANGE("data", "Sheet1!B1:B");},
"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 != ''")`

Comment: access denied to your spreadsheet, pls share!

Comment: Sorry, just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply query to each sheet :

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RwSw-JvLO3yqJxwQ9FBdfTcUjtSKlMMF3GF0Al-mGu8", "Sheet1!A4:A"), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0);
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RwSw-JvLO3yqJxwQ9FBdfTcUjtSKlMMF3GF0Al-mGu8", "Sheet1!B4:B"), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0);
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1RwSw-JvLO3yqJxwQ9FBdfTcUjtSKlMMF3GF0Al-mGu8", "Sheet3!A1:A"), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

try?

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("id", "Sheet1!A1:A"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("id", "Sheet2!B1:B")}, 
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

---

### update:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1yr5f4eMsnbUuhzdCNQk2RkKmXoyU3WHhn1PBcWqZvgU", "Sheet1!A4:A");
        IMPORTRANGE("1yr5f4eMsnbUuhzdCNQk2RkKmXoyU3WHhn1PBcWqZvgU", "Sheet1!B4:B");
        IMPORTRANGE("1yr5f4eMsnbUuhzdCNQk2RkKmXoyU3WHhn1PBcWqZvgU", "Sheet3!A1:A")},
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

or faster:

```
=QUERY({FLATTEN(IMPORTRANGE("1yr5f4eMsnbUuhzdCNQk2RkKmXoyU3WHhn1PBcWqZvgU", "Sheet1!A4:B"));
                IMPORTRANGE("1yr5f4eMsnbUuhzdCNQk2RkKmXoyU3WHhn1PBcWqZvgU", "Sheet3!A1:A")},
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: works partially, if I want to pull data from two different sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet3) I get a #REF! error. Pulling data from Sheet1 columns A and B also only works if B1 does NOT contain any data. IF B1 contains data, A1:A is overwritten and only data pulled from B1:B is displayed.

Comment: @MariusHempel can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yr5f4eMsnbUuhzdCNQk2RkKmXoyU3WHhn1PBcWqZvgU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MariusHempel answer updated